# Combining Laravel + Vue.js got Error ( Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/App' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist\resources\js' )

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I did everything like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHSipe7pSac but after that I got this error :

> :( "ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 4:0-28 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/app'

this is my  **/resources/js/app.js** file

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';

import App from './vue/App';

const app = new Vue(
    {
        el: '#app',
        components: { app }
    }
);
```

and this is my **webpack.mix.js** file

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Comment: What is the path to your `App.vue` file?

Comment: What is here `resources/js/vue/App.js`?

Comment: Also you shouldn't mix using imports and requires

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Vue `const` itself as a component. (Aside from the other correct comments on your question)

```
import App from './vue/App'; <----- Uppercase App

const app = new Vue( <----- Lowercase app
    {
        el: '#app',
        components: { app } <------- Lowercase app
    }
);
```

Try changing those up. But even better, improve your naming. Like `Home.vue`

Happy coding!